# fswebcam not working

Tags: camera, fswebcam

When I try to use fswebcam by running `fswebcam --save test.jpg`, it works once every time I reboot my raspberry pi. Then it gets to "Capturing frame" before giving an error that says

```
spca561_decode() failed
```

and writes a photo that's completely black except for the banner on the bottom. I'm using a Logitech QuickCam Chat. I've tried unpluging/repluging camera several times. It's not a power problem, because it gives the same error with no usb running over vnc. Any help is greatly appreciated.